# Electron + React + Serialport issues

Tags: reactjs, electron, serial-port

I am working on a desktop application, which must read data from a serialport. As a web developer i have choosen to go for React and Electron. These two can work well together but i am not able to use the serialport npm package with them. There are examples, where serialport is working with electron, but as soon as there is a react included it is not working. There are many obstacles, and i am struggling for few days now.

The farest i have got is, that the serialport package was throwing error, because the fs module was not available, message: 'exists is not a function'. (Rebuilding the serialport package did not help)

Is there any chance these three can work together?

Thank you

Comment: Hi :) Have you been able to make that three work together? I've been struggling with this for a couple of days and it seems very unlikely to succeed ;)

Comment: Hi, unfortunately no. But found another way to use react + serialport and delpoy it as pc app. I have used https://nwjs.io/